# Match different screen size

Tags: android, layout, size

my problem is quite simple, i never did this before but now i'm forced to search for a solution.

**working with layout-normal**

Let's say i have a image background set to match_parent, with 3 different points on it, on that points i should place buttons, i added the buttons and set some margin dp's till i meet the points. for example: layout_marginTop="50dp"

on the preview screen it looks ok, but when i start some emulators from the same size category "layout-normal"

3.7inch; 4.0inch; 4.65inch ... it looks different. it looks ok only on the device size i got the preview

What should i do? what can i do?

i tryed to fix the image, created a linear layout, set the image as background, set the size  of the screen (let's say 400x250) and added the buttons in the layout.

but now when i run it in different emulators i get empty space and the image does not fit the entire screen.

Hrrrrrrr! what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Get your ImageView Size with a onPreDrawListener, or if it fill the Screen you can get it with getDisplaySize

You know the points in your image where to place your Buttons:

orginal image 480x800 -> button1 left:XX px top:xx px

new size 720x1280 -> button1 left: YY px top: YY px

with this info you can calculate where to place the Button on real device with an other Resolution than 480x800 (using the rule of three)

then set your margins programaticly

Answer (score 0):

*actualy i found out that android documentation gives you other posibilities in layouts arranging.*

**--** layout-normal; layout-small; layout-large; layout-xlarge

**--** layout-sw300dp; layout-sw360dp; layout-sw450dp; layout-sw600dp;
   layout-sw800dp; *where sw means smallest available width required by your layout resources*

**--** layout-w300dp; layout-w360dp; layout-w450dp; layout-w600dp; layout-w800dp; *where w means the minimum width required for the layout*

**--** layout-h200dp; layout-h260dp; *... where h means the minimum height required for the layout*

i used to give them the smallest available width.